# Ed25519 digital signatures in React Native

Tags: react-native, cryptography, ed25519

I'm building an app in React Native (currently using Expo) that needs to be able to perform digital signatures using the `Ed25519` digital signature algorithm.

As a newcomer to the React Native ecosystem, it's unclear which libraries to use or what approach is best for this. Specifically I am looking for:

- A well maintained library
- Unlikely to have significant security issues
- Works on iOS, Android and Web
- Can sign an arbitrary sequence of bytes, using a private key derived from a Ed25519 seed
- Not too many dubious transitive dependencies

It's not a requirement that the signing is particularly fast: correctness, security and maintainability are more important.

What would be the recommended library / approach in 2023?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest taking a look at https://github.com/jedisct1/libsodium and https://github.com/cossacklabs/themis. I believe both meet your criteria.

Comment: It looks like Libsodium is not supporting js/react-native.
Also, Themis does not have anything related to Ed25519 in their documents.

Comment: There appears to be several bindings for using libsodium with react native. Themis is a different beast, it provides high level cryptographic functions ready-to-use, which often is a better choice than implementing it all from low level cryptographic primitives. But, yes, it seems you're right in that it's not using ed25519 for message signatures, but rather ECDSA P-256. The libraries were only suggested for further evaluation by the OP. Strictly speaking Themis does not appear to meet the OPs' specific criteria with ed25519 though, good that you pointed it out.